# Operator with powers

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a vector space V. Let $K_r$ and $W_r$ denote the kernel and image, respectively, of $T^r$.

a) Show that $K_1 \subset K_2 \subset \dots$ and that $W_1 \supset W_2 \supset \dots$

b)The following conditions might or might not hold for a particular value of r: $$(1)K_r=K_{r+1}, (2)W_r=W_{r+1}, (3) W_r \cap K_1=\{0\}, (4) W_1+K_r=V.$$
Find all implications among the conditions $(1)-(4)$ when $V$ is finite-dimensional and then when $V$ is infinite-dimensional.

Could someone give me a structure of how to solve these questions ? I really am having difficulty here.

Answer (score 2):

Many problems are very little more than just writing down definitions, and seeing that everything lines up.

For example, the phrase $K_1 \subseteq K_2$ is equivalent to the phrase:

> If $x \in K_1$, then $x \in K_2$.

The phrase $x \in K_1$ is equivalent to the phrase $T(x) = 0$. Thus, the phrase $K_1 \subseteq K_2$ is equivalent to the phrase

> If $T(x) = 0$, then $x \in K_2$.

and so forth. Using this for part (a), you'll eventually get to something that is either obvious or, possibly even trivial.

Comment: +1 for the first sentence. Most people get blocked when they see the problem and forget about writing down the definitions.

Comment: @Hurkyl Could you give me a hint for b) as well ?

Comment: @Duronman Can you help me with b) as well ?

Comment: The same procedure would surely help with (b) (I misread it the first time: I thought there were quantifiers $\forall r$). I haven't worked through it to know how obvious the end result would be to work with.